# How to call initial function for Controller in the AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I wrote some controller based ui-route.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        views: {
            'rightMainView' : {
                templateUrl: "dashboard/",
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('dashboard.all', {
        url: "all/",
        resolve: {
            dashboards: ['dashboards', function(dashboards){
                return dashboards.all();
            }]
        },
        templateUrl: 'dashboard/all/',
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'dashboards', DashboardAllCtrl]
    })
;
...

function DashboardCtrl($scope, $state) {
    $state.go('dashboard.all');
}
```

This code will be work at first. But if i click same link for dashboard (re-call dashboard/ url), then the $state.go function is not called.

so I just need call initial function for controller. How I can achieve this?

Comment: where is your 'dashboard.all' state setting?

Comment: I added dashboard.all state setting

Comment: value of `templateUrl` should be a route to a template file or a ng-template like "example.html".

Comment: and always check your browser console to see what error happened